# Using a button on a cell to pass data in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, button

I have 2 VCs, one of them is called HomeVC the other is DetailVC. I have a table view on HomeVC which displays cells with a label and a button. DetailVC just has a label. I am displaying an array of strings on the table view and when the button on the cell is clicked i want to carry the text in the label to the DetailVC's label.

Now i can easily do this with either didSelectRowAt method or using indexPathForSelectedRow in prepare segue method. But both cases requires me to tap on the cell itself but not the button.

I am just a beginner in swift. But to explain this there shouldn't be need for much code. So if you can, please explain with detail.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: add a target to your button in cellForRow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In cellForRowAt add target to button i.e

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellID", for: indexPath)
        cell.button.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.button.addTarget(self, action: Selector("buttonAction:"), for: .touchUpInside)

        // other cell element setup
        return cell
    }
```

And at button action get the item from array using button tag i.e

```
func buttonAction(sender: UIButton) {
    let data = tableArray[sender.tag]
    // logic to pass present detailVC
}
```

Hope this will work!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using collection view you can use the following

```
    // Set The Click Action On Button
    cell.bProfileImage.addTarget(self, action: #selector(connected(sender:)), for:
         .touchUpInside)
    cell.bProfileImage.tag = indexPath.row
```

Then in your function

```
// Function For TouchUpInside For Cell
@objc func connected(sender: UIButton) {
    let data = individualChatsListArray[sender.tag]
    print(data.name)
}
```